# Symlink contents of a folder not the folder itsself

Tags: windows, symbolic-link

I am trying to create a symlink, this is a little scetch

```
a 
|--b
|--c
|--d
   |-bunch of files
|--e
   |-file1
```

I would like to make a symlink that links the contents of folder a, however i should be able to add files and folders without having to refresh the symlink, is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

I found that creating a junction is the best possibility to solve my problem (under windows). I am using the Free link shell extension to do this in an easy way